# Does the DC-DC converter need exact values?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I'll be using a DC-DC converter in my system. The servo motor i'll be using is HS-755MG http://hitecrcd.com/products/servos/giant-servos/analog-giant-servos/hs-755mg-metal-gear-giant-scale-servo/product

Does the DC-DC converter need to have exact same values or just the voltage?

Comment: Exact values of what?

Comment: Voltage and ampere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DC-DC converter should be capable of handling at least 1,800 mA and should be within the voltage range of the motor.

(Other values do not relate to the DC DC converter, or what other values you thought should be 'compatible' ?)

Comment: None other than the Amps and voltage. Can I use a DC DC converter with higher amp than 1.8A? or should the converter i use be 6V 1.8A out?

Comment: Yes (I said: at least). The adapter will deliver what is 'requested' by the device. If the device requests more the adapter will overheat, but if the device requests less than the adapter can deliver all is ok. So make sure the adapter is AT LEAST 1,800 mA (preferably a bit more to have some headroom). Note that 6 V is on the limit (what happens if it deliver 6.1 V? this might damage the motor).